# Set a Google Analytics goal based on events from 2 domains

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using Google analytics for JS.
I have a site where users click on a button and then redirected to another sub domain for registration.
Can I set a Goal which will combine the redirecting to registration page, and completing the registration ( which is available to me with an Event)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Orr**, that should be quite straight forward. Just setup the tracking for [subdomains](http://www.ericmobley.net/guide-to-tracking-multiple-subdomains-in-google-analytics/), which will make all the data accessible in one account/reporting view - setup the goals accordingly (use whole URLs instead of just *Document Path*) and you should be all set!

Comment: It rather looks like Orr wanted to include the redirect as necessary condition (i.e. exclude people who have reached the registration page via other ways) else his ssetup would already do want he wanted. I don't think this is covered by you answer.

Comment: Eike, maybe I understood the question wrong - if so, Orr could you please verify?

Comment: Eike ,If I would follow this instructions - then the whole data of the sub domains and main domain will be available with the same analitycs site? How will I know how to distinguish between them?

Comment: Orr, if you set up a filter to add a hostname as well, instead of just seeeing the *Document Path* (eg /products/ABC123/ you will see www.hostname.com/products/ABC123/)

Comment: and for subdomaing, that would be subdomain.hostanme.com/whatever